# Is using a String Wrapper a better design?

Tags: java

I was suggested to use String Wrapper instead of String for the purpose to make it clear what the string stand for.

For example, I have the following enum.

```
public enum Priority
{
   PRIORITY_URGENT("urgent"),
   PRIORITY_HIGH("high"),
   PRIORITY_LOW("low");

   private String _piorityLevel;
   private Priority(String level)
   {
     _priorityLevel = level;
   }

   public String getPriorityLevel()
   {
     return _priorityLevel;
   }
   ....
}
```

Is it a better design to wrap the priority level String as a new class like PriorityLevel to make it clear that the string stands for priority level as below?

```
public enum Priority
{
   PRIORITY_URGENT(new PriorityLevel("urgent")),
   PRIORITY_HIGH(new PriorityLevel("high")),
   PRIORITY_LOW(new PriorityLevel("low"));

   private PriorityLevel _piorityLevel;
   private Priority(PriorityLevel level)
   {
     _priorityLevel = level;
   }

   public PriorityLevel getPriorityLevel()
   {
     return _priorityLevel;
   }
   ....
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is enough for an answer, but the way I read it, the `Priority` enum already is a string wrapper, so adding a second level of wrapper for `PriorityLevel` seems redundant to me.

Answer (score 2):

Lack of programmer-defined implicit conversion operators in Java makes writing string wrappers somewhat cumbersome. The `toString` convention helps, but in many cases the conversion will be explicit.

Think of a common action a user of your API is going to take on the `PriorityLevel` property: everywhere they need it as a `String` they would have to write

```
Priority priority = Priority.PRIORITY_URGENT;
String level = priority.getPriorityLevel().toString();
```

The last `toString()` call is annoying. Although you can avoid it in situations like this

```
System.out.println("This job has " + priority.getPriorityLevel() + "priority");
```

it's better to not have to think about it at all. After all, an `enum` already provides adequate wrapping to your strings, so a second level is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is good to not fall into [primitive obsession](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession) too deeply, but as your example is an `enum`, you already have *strong typing* in place and there is no apparent reason to wrap the string values into an additional layer.

The reason why you want to avoid excessive use of `String` and other primitives is to make code express the domain concepts more explicitly, and to avoid (at compile-time) simple programming errors like assigning a parameter in the wrong position when the method signature is something like

```
public String doSomething(String name, String id, String address)
```

instead of

```
public Result doSomething(Name name, Id id, Address address)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first enum is enough. The second wrapper is unnecessary.

That said, why don't you just do this.

```
public enum Priority {
   URGENT,
   HIGH,
   LOW;
}
```

And use the `toString()` if you need the string representation.

```
for (Priority priority : Priority.values()) {
    System.out.print(priority);
}
```

Prints:

> URGENT
>
> HIGH
>
> LOW